# Remote Desktop Connection Audit

Tags: remote, desktop, audit

My company recently fired someone. They said, they are auditing that person's electronic activity. We all have Remote Desktop connections that we use to work from home. Do you know what level of information they can access on rdp activity? For example, will they know exactly what you did while connected, like working on a word document or excel spreadsheet, or will they just know when you logged on, how long, etc?

Comment: What's stoking your interest?

Comment: Can be a websense, or anything even not rdp related. Buy a beer to the sysadmin and ask him. We cant help there, as maybe its a lie and they invented a excuse to fire him, or they just withnessed him.

Comment: The key takeaway here is that while it is hypothetically possible to monitor virtually everything that a person does while logged in to a computer, you have to have the auditing set up properly ahead of time. It won't help you to only turn on all the right auditing after the fact.

Comment: My concern is simple.  The culture here is not the greatest, bullying from above is rampant.  The threat of firing is floating around.  It feels like they want to beat everyone into submission.  I feel like if I copied a file for a legit reason and they decide to audit everyone, they'll just can me.  I spoke to a friend of mine that says that if server upgrades were done, the info that occurred before then may be unable to be audited, as it may have been discarded.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a Windows desktop, this is straight from the horse's mouth:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn319078.aspx

Pretty much everything, if they have auditing set up.